# SUM Multiple Columns by Group BY

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, sum

I have these datas on my database

```
Purchase ID: 0012 <br>
Product: 1 <br>
Delivered: 100

Pruchase ID: 0013<br>
Product: 1<br>
Delivered: 10
```

When i sum the same products, it should be **110** but when I use this query, the sum will be **440**

```
SELECT `purchase_orders`.`product`, SUM(purchase_orders.delivered) as system_count, `products`.`code`
FROM `purchase_orders`
JOIN `products` ON `products`.`id` = `purchase_orders`.`product`
WHERE `purchase_orders`.`delivery_status` = 4
GROUP BY `purchase_orders`.`product`
```

Can anyone help me what is wrong with my SQl?

Comment: Hi Hayle, Your first inner join is wrong: products`.`id` = `purchase_orders`.`product`. It should be product to product. But thats not enough to explain the problem. The full schema of the tables and more data would help. For example you use column delivery_status but it doesnt exist in the description you give of your tables. Its tough for us to get and find a solution with little info

Comment: @hayle . .  . Without sample data and desired results, I don't think anyone can really help.

Answer (score 0):

You should `GROUP BY` **products.code** as well.

Like below

```
SELECT `purchase_orders`.`product`, SUM(purchase_orders.delivered) as system_count, `products`.`code`
FROM `purchase_orders`
JOIN `products` ON `products`.`id` = `purchase_orders`.`product`
WHERE `purchase_orders`.`delivery_status` = 4
GROUP BY `purchase_orders`.`product`, `products`.`code`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select po.Product, sum(po.Delivered) as count from purchase_orders po
group by po.Product
```